# How to handle multiple ASP.NET WebForms Submissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am writing an ASP.NET WebForm for a reservation system with a fixed number of seats for each time slot. Every time I edit the general availability database, I run this script:

```
foreach (SqlParameter param in sqlCmd.Parameters)
    {
    if (int.Parse(param.Value.ToString()) < 0 || int.Parse(param.Value.ToString()) > 60)
    {
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", "alert('We're sorry, it seems like someone claimed the vacant spot before your request could finish. please try again with valid paramters');", true);
         Server.TransferRequest(Request.RawUrl, false);
         return;
     }
}
```

Where it iterates over the parameters I'm inserting to see if there are any values that would be below zero (they filled up too many) or above the maximum availability (due to wrap-around from 0 ->255) before actually writing. If there is a problem, we can see that it throws an alert to the reservation screen.

Is there a "proper" way to do this in ASP.NET WebForms? I'm a little bit worried about what would happen if, say 100 people made a reservation at once (edge case). Since the whole point is to strictly limit the seats (for legal reasons), is there a way to do this without switching to MVC?

Is there a specific order that the code behind processes requests, such that submissions to synchronous functions are naturally processed in a queue?

Answer (score 0):

I would say check availability in db before making call. Seat allocation ideally should happen as db transaction.